# Open popup on button/image click

Tags: jquery, html

This code is working to open vanillabox on image click but i need to implement this code for button click.. i have tried with click() method but it doesnot work..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function(){
        $('#grouped-image-list a').vanillabox();
    });
});
```

The above code defines test as button id..please check html below

```
<button id="test" name="test" value="Click1">click1</button>
<div class="double-column">
    <div class="column1">
        <ul id="grouped-image-list" class="link-list">
            <li><a href="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-1.png" title="Main Screen"><img src="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-1.png" border="0" width="300" height="300"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-2.png" title="Screen2"><img src="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-2.png" border="0" width="300" height="300"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-3.png" title="Screen3"><img src="HD_Wallpaper/App-screen-3.png" border="0" width="300" height="300"/></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#grouped-image-list a').vanillabox();
      $('#test').click(function(){
             $('#grouped-image-list').find('a:first').trigger('click');
      });
  });
```

Make sure you had added css & js of vanillabox.